# Using `map[string]interface{}` and `[]interface{}` in terraform provider framework

Tags: go, terraform, terraform-provider

I am trying to construct a terraform provider that can deal with arbitrary map and list inputs. (I am using the provider "framework")

Let's assume my upstream API expects a JSON payload like this (in psuedo-code):

```
name: string
input1: map(any)
input2: list(any)
```

So we could send this:

```
{
  "name": "foobar"
  "input1":  {
      "apple": "tree"
    },
  "input2": ["hello", 123]
}
```

But also this:

```
{
  "name": "foobaz"
  "input1":  {
      "this": {
         "is": "nested"
      },
     "this-though": "isnt"
    },
  "input2": [{"here": "things}]
}
```

etc.

To achieve the above I am using the following as my payload in the API client:

```
type MyModel struct {
    Name   string                 `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Input1 map[string]interface{} `json:"input1,omitempty"`
    Input2 []interface{}          `json:"input2,omitempty"`
}
```

For the resource schema I am using:

```
  resp.Schema = schema.Schema{
    Description: "Manages a smart contract.",
    Attributes: map[string]schema.Attribute{
        "ID": schema.StringAttribute{
            Computed:    true,
        },
        "Name": schema.StringAttribute{
            Required:    true,
        },
        "input1": schema.MapAttribute{ <---- What should this be?
            Required:    true,
        },
        "input2": schema.ListAttribute{ <---- What should this be?
            Required:    true,
        },
    },
```

Below is an example of how I am attempting to implement `Create`

```
// Create a new resource.
func (r *myModelResource) Create(ctx context.Context, req resource.CreateRequest, resp *resource.CreateResponse) {
    // Retrieve values from plan
    var plan myModelModel
    diags := req.Plan.Get(ctx, &plan)
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }

    newMyModel := client.MyModel{
        Name:   plan.Name.ValueString(),
        Input1: plan.Input1.ValueString(),  // <---- THIS IS WRONG. What should I do here?
        Input2: plan.Input2.ValueString(),  // <---- THIS IS WRONG. What should I do here?
    }

    // Update existing myModel
    myModel, err := r.client.CreateMyModel(newMyModel)
    if err != nil {
        resp.Diagnostics.AddError(
            "Error Updating MyModel",
            "Could not update MyModel, unexpected error: "+err.Error(),
        )
        return
    }

    plan.Name = types.StringValue(myModel.Name)
    plan.Input1 = types.StringValue(myModel.Input1) // <---- THIS IS WRONG. What should I do here?
    plan.Input2 = types.StringValue(myModel.Input2) // <---- THIS IS WRONG. What should I do here?

    // Set state to fully populated data
    diags = resp.State.Set(ctx, plan)
    resp.Diagnostics.Append(diags...)
    if resp.Diagnostics.HasError() {
        return
    }
}
```

What should my schema attribute types be, and how should I do the conversion to and from MyModel?

Comment: From Terraform's perspective, the closest description of this API schema would be: `name` is `string`, `input1` is `any`, and `input2` is `any`. `any` in Terraform means any _single_ type, so in `map(any)` and `list(any)` the elements all still need to have the same type, but Terraform tries to infer that single type automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately I think at the moment the framework doesn't have strong (or any?) support for attributes being totally dynamically typed. There's an open issue for it here with some more information on the current state of things: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/issues/147

Comment: If you need this to work today then I'd suggest declaring a single attribute of type `string` and have users assign the result of a `jsonencode` function call to it. If you name the argument with a `_json` suffix then potentially later you could deprecate it in favor of a dynamically-typed argument without a suffix once better framework support is available. Using strings containing JSON for remote systems that accept arbitrary (or semi-arbitrary) JSON is a common pattern in providers today.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response. I was afraid you might tell me that is the workaround I would need. I am a bit hesitant to use it since I am not sure how to prevent differences client-side on the formatting of the json string from causing terraform to think the resource needs to be updated. I mean sure, if client-side you always pass a map into `jsonencode` then fine, but you could just as easily just type in the text or use `file` read from the JSON from disk. Is there a way to do some pre-formatting in the provider before it does its comparison between existing and new?

Comment: @MartinAtkins That is correct: one must specify the static type in the attribute schema vis a vis `types.MapType{ElemType: types.StringType}`. I would love for that functionality myself, but it will probably never happen due to the questionable cost/benefit, and the current significant workload of the team. It does feel like a fun exercise with generics though (thank you 1.18).

Comment: The plugin framework has a notion of "semantic equals" which you can use by creating a custom type (derived from one of the built-ins) that has a more liberal definition of "equal" than the raw type would perform. You could potentially use that by applying normalizations to both the before and after value (e.g. minify and sort the object properties by name) and then reporting the two values as "semantically equal" if the two normalized forms are the same.

Comment: Here's the interface you'd need to implement to define a derivation of string with a custom semantic equality rule: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework@v1.4.2/types/basetypes#StringValuableWithSemanticEquals